# Upgrading Django from 2.0 to 2.2 breaks custom authentication

Tags: django

the files below is about custom authentication, mainly to use email as username and it works fine on Django 2.0.x. I'm starting a fresh new project in Django 2.2 and it doesn't work anymore. Why?

## authmanager/helper_functions.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def _login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
def _logout(request):
    request.session.flush()
    logout(request)
    return True
```

## authmanager/mybackend.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth import backends
from .models import User

class MyCustomBackend(backends.ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            if user and check_password(password, user.password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk = user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

## settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['crm.authmanager.mybackend.MyCustomBackend',]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authmanager.User'
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error.  But I fixed now, after taking a look at the Django's source code.

```
    def authenticate(self, request, **credentials):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=credentials['username'])
            if user and check_password(credentials['password'], user.password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

```